# Parent object eager load nested associations Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through, eager-loading

In Rails 4 i have the following models

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sons
 has_many :grand_sons, through: sons

 scope :load_tree, (id) -> {Parent.includes(sons: [:grand_sons]).find(id)}
end

class Son < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  has_many :grand_sons
end

class GrandSon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :son
end
```

With load_tree i would like to obtain an object like:

```
{ 
  id: 1, 
  sons: [
          { 
            id: 1, 
            parent_id: 1, 
            grand_sons:[ { id: 1, son_id: 1, } , ...]
          }, ...
        ]
 }
```

But after doing `tree = Parent.load_tree(1)` i got `tree # <Parent id=1>` `tree.sons #[<Son id=1>, <Son id =2>]` so it seems that i am not able to eager load all the objects, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Parent.includes(:sons, {:sons => :grand_sons}).find(id)
```

My understanding is, that you must specify the relationship for nested associations explicitly.

Comment: +1 Also, for anyone wondering about even deeper nesting i.e. great-grandson syntax: `Parent.includes(:sons, { :sons => { :grand_sons => :great_grand_sons } }).find(id)`